# how to add a XML Node inside all nodes in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a column in sql database with type XML. I want to add a new node `EFDRow` with same value in all nodes with name `GoodsSerial`.

```
<Serials>
  <GoodsSerial>
    <GSerialSCredit>2015/08/11</GSerialSCredit>
    <GSerialECredit>2015/08/11</GSerialECredit>
    <GSerialStart>1</GSerialStart>
    <GSerialEnd>5</GSerialEnd>
  </GoodsSerial>
  <GoodsSerial>
    <GSerialSCredit>2015/08/11</GSerialSCredit>
    <GSerialECredit>2015/08/11</GSerialECredit>
    <GSerialStart>10</GSerialStart>
    <GSerialEnd>15</GSerialEnd>
  </GoodsSerial>
</Serials>
```

I have tried this Code

```
UPDATE Tbl
SET SerialXml.modify('insert <EFDRow>{sql:column("EFDRow")}</EFDRow> into (/Serials/GoodsSerial)[1]')
```

But it adds the EFDRow node only to first GoodsSerial node.

Comment: its not clearly understand. Can you show, what will be the output? update your que.

Comment: possible duplicate of [xml-sql: update multiple nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712841/xml-sql-update-multiple-nodes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can shred your XML no `/Serials/GoodsSerial` and the rebuild it with the value of `EFDRow` added using `for xml path`.

```sql
update dbo.Tbl
set SerialXml = (
                select GS.X.query('*'),
                       EFDRow
                from SerialXml.nodes('/Serials/GoodsSerial') as GS(X)
                for xml path('GoodsSerial'), root('Serials'), type
                );
```

`GS.X.query('*')` will give you all the nodes that already exist in `GoodsSerial`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/290ae/2)

Answer (score 0):

Modify can only replace 1 value at a time.
You must loop through all node:

[Updating all nodes by condition with xml to sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763068/updating-all-nodes-by-condition-with-xml-to-sql)

[xml-sql: update multiple nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712841/xml-sql-update-multiple-nodes)